# This delegate does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, delegates

I need to add an element to a Winform ListView control from other thread, so I am using a delegate, this way:

```
    private delegate void AddMessageLogCallback(string message);

    public void AddMessageLog(string message)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(new AddMessageLogCallback(AddMessageLog), message);
        else
        {
            lstLogs.Items.Add(message).EnsureVisible();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the Invoke does nothing, not even throws an exception.

I have used this kind of delegates before and never had problems. What different is at this time?

Comment: have you tried declaring your method virtual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as desired with the test code below, so the problem should be something else.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddMessageLog("local message");
}

private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => AddMessageLog("async message"));
}
```

Btw, I would mention that there is no need to define a new `AddMessageLogCallback` delegate and to call the `AddMessageLog` recursively. So a more simple (and maybe cleaner) solution:

```
public void AddMessageLog(string message)
{
    Action addLog = () => lstLogs.Items.Add(message).EnsureVisible();
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(addLog);
    else
        addLog();
}
```